# Optimizing channel sends

Tags: rust

I have a simple program that I'd like to optimize. (I don't care about ordering of messages)

```rust
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

use tokio::task;
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};

async fn do_sleep() {
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(32);
    let tx2 = tx.clone();

    let models = vec![1, 2, 3];

    for model in models {
        tx.send(format!("sending {}", model)).await;
    }

    while let Some(message) = rx.recv().await {
        do_sleep().await;
        println!("GOT = {}", message);
    }
}
```

Concretely, I want to optimize the `tx.send()`. What is the tradeoff to wrapping every `tx.send()` in a future vs a tokio task?

Comment: According to [tokio::task::spawn](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn.html), its argument must be a Future... So what then does "future vs task" mean?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to optimize? `send` isn't very expensive, and if you want it to go faster, you'd have to use a different channel implementation. But as it is, this is a  trivial program that isn't even all that asynchronous.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I'm trying to optimize for speed. 

Yes, this is a trivial program, but let's say there were a million models to process. 

In the current implementation, every model is "blocked" by the execution of the previous model, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequentially awaiting the `send()`s guarantees ordering wrt. what the receiver observes, `tokio::spawn(chan.send(msg))` can lead to reordering.

`tokio::spawn` removes any kind of backpressure on the producer when the consumer is slow, i.e. `mpsc::channel(buf_size)` puts a limit of `buf_size` messages in the internal buffer before senders have to wait. `buf_size` puts an upper bound on the memory consumption and forces the sender to slow down in case of a slow consumer.

You can increase the buffer size to a value that can handle bursts of messages if you want to keep a hard upper bound on memory or you can use an [unbounded channel](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/fn.unbounded_channel.html) which never waits on `send()`.

If the producer always and continuously outpaces the receiver, then you'll eventually run into memory issues.

It's likely that you will see more improvements by parallelizing the handling of messages on the receiving end.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Yes, in this application, I don't care about ordering. Sorry I didn't mention that. 

The main drawback I see is that the design is bottlenecked on a single receiver channel.

So for example, the execution of an expensive model could "block" another model behind it, right? 


The receiving end just does one IO heavy operation (simulated as sleep in the example) and it needs to awaited on

Comment: You can do something like `while let Some(msg) = rx.recv().await { tokio::spawn(handler(msg)) }` or another solution that allows you to concurrently process messages at the receiver. If you still want to maintain an upper bound of parallel models you can use a `Semaphore` or similar. You can also place the handler futures into something like `FuturesUnordered` and `select!` over the `recv()` and the futures if you need to operate on the output

Comment: > if the producer always and continuously outpaces the receiver, then you'll eventually run into memory issues. 

Can you expand a bit on this? If consumer has too many messages and it's blocked by the receiver, why will it hit memory issues, as opposed to CPU issues? Seems like CPU would be the bottleneck because of the increased waiting time, right?

Comment: Imagine a producer sending at a rate of 2 message per second and a consumer processing at 1 message per second. After 1 second, there is 1 unprocessed message in the queue, after 2 seconds 2, after 60 seconds, 60 messages, etc. Eventually the queue reaches a length that exceeds the available memory and your process will likely exit.